# Java RMI parameter passing

Tags: java, rmi

I got a question about java rmi. I know that remote-objects will be passed as a reference to the origin object. Serializable objects and value types are passed by value.

What happens, if I have a list with remote-objects, that will be passed as a parameter? Lists are serializable. A list of ints would be passed by value. What happens with a list of remote objects? The list could be serialized and the objects? Will the receiver get a list of serialized stubs and work on the origin objects?

Comment: All arguments must be serializable - so as yourself a question - is remote stub serializable?

Comment: yes, remote stubs are serializable

Comment: @Antoniossss A remote object passed as a parameter or return value doesn't have to be serializable, but it will be passed as its stub, which is serializable.